# Is it possible to rewrite “who had” to “having”?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to say this?

> 1. He married a woman **who had** once committed adultery.
> 2. He married a woman **having** once committed adultery.

The latter uses "having" as an adjective clause, like a box *containing* ten apples.

A real life example:

> Nextcoin, or commonly known as NXT, is a relatively new altcoin **having** been released in December of 2013.
> <sub>Source: [cointelegraph.com, *NXT*](http://cointelegraph.com/news/112213/nxt)</sub>

I want to know whether it is ambiguous or not. I want to know about the grammatical felicity of this.

Comment: The first sentence is clearer than the second one. The second one causes ambiguity. In the second sentence who committed adultery is not clear. Many will end up guessing "he" committed adultery.

Comment: @Man_From_India You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @user08742 Can you please elaborate?

Comment: That real life example is different, it doesn't apply to this.

Comment: *Is it possible to rewrite "who had" to "having"? ~ If you want to stay clear, **NO!** About your *real life example*, more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 5):

It is technically still a correct sentence, but they have different meanings.

> He married a woman who had once committed adultery.

Is clear that the woman was adulterous.

> He married a woman having once committed adultery.

This actually suggests that he had committed adultery, although it doesn't say it explicitly. To say it explicitly it would be this:

> He married a woman, having once committed adultery.

Or

> Having once committed adultery, he married a woman.

**But the example you gave still implies it, and there is nothing wrong with assuming that the man is adulterous.**

---

> You are not addressing the real life example in the thread. And there is no comma so the second sentence doesn't mean that.

The real life example is different to the non real life ones:

> Nextcoin, or commonly known as NXT, is a relatively new altcoin having been released in December of 2013.

1. It has a comma
2. It is not ambiguous
3. "Nextcoin, or commonly known as NXT, is a relatively new altcoin ***who had*** been released in December of 2013." makes absolutely no sense.

NB: It should ataually be:

> Nextcoin, <del>or</del> commonly known as NXT, is a relatively new altcoin having been released in December of 2013.

With no "*or*"

> you are not addressing why it CANNOT mean the same thing. therefore not an answer.

You asked weather or not it meant that. I answered - it can mean the same, it is **ambiguous**. If you believe you know the answer, please self answer.

If you don't want to accept this as the answer - fine, but both this and Man_From_India's answers are correct.

Comment: You are not addressing the real life example in the thread. And there is no comma so the second sentence doesn't mean that.

Comment: you are not addressing why it CANNOT mean the same thing. thereore not an answer.

Comment: I agree. Though in latter case, I'd start the sentence with *Having once committed adultery, he married a woman.'* +1

Comment: @User08742 - "there is no comma so the second sentence doesn't mean that." - wrong. If you think my answer is wrong, please down vote and post your own, correct answer.

Comment: @Tim Nice answer +1

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is clearer than the second one. The second one causes ambiguity. In the second sentence who committed adultery is not clear. Many will end up guessing **"he"** committed adultery.

Comment: but no room for ambiguity coz there is no comma before the having.

Comment: @user08742 I guess even with a comma, it's still ambiguous.

Comment: Downvote? Why? What's wrong with this? +1 The OP seems to be confused by downvoting the other answer as well.

Comment: @MaulikV Even I was thinking the same things :) thanks friend.